# Java beginner: nullpointerexception error

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm developing a library management program (it's an assignment from an online course), and I can't solve a nullpointerexception error at runtime.

This is the program so far:

```
//file Library.java
public class Library {

String address;
Book[] collection;
int collectionCounter = 0;

    // Add the missing implementation to this class
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create two libraries
        Library firstLibrary = new Library("10 Main St.");
        Library secondLibrary = new Library("228 Liberty St.");
        // Add four books to the first library
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Da Vinci Code"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Le Petit Prince"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("A Tale of Two Cities"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Lord of the Rings"));
    }

    //Constructor
    public Library(String libraryName)
    {
        address = libraryName;
        collectionCounter = 0;
    }

    //Methods
    public void addBook(Book newBook)
    {
        System.out.println(this.collectionCounter);
        this.collection[this.collectionCounter] = newBook;
        this.collectionCounter += 1;
    }
```

And the other .java file, for the `Book` class:

```
public class Book {
String title;
boolean borrowed;

    // Creates a new Book
    public Book(String bookTitle) {
        // Implement this method
        title = bookTitle;
        borrowed = false;
    }
    // Marks the book as rented
    public void rented() {
        // Implement this method
        this.borrowed = true;
    }

    // Marks the book as not rented
    public void returned() {
        // Implement this method
        this.borrowed = false;
    }

    // Returns true if the book is rented, false otherwise
    public boolean isBorrowed() {
        // Implement this method
        return this.borrowed;
    }

    // Returns the title of the book
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {

        // Small test of the Book class
        Book example = new Book("The Da Vinci Code");
        System.out.println("Title (should be The Da Vinci Code): " + example.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): " + example.isBorrowed());
        example.rented();
        System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be true): " + example.isBorrowed());
        example.returned();
        System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): " + example.isBorrowed());
    }
```

}

This is the program output:

```
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Library.addBook(Library.java:59)
    at Library.main(Library.java:14)
```

I understand the error is caused by the array of books, but I don't really know what to do, I had never seen an object instantiation as an argument for a method. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create your array `collection` in order to be able to put anything into it. Replace

```
Book[] collection;
```

by

```
Book[] collection = new Book[BOOK_COLLECTION_SIZE];
```

with `BOOK_COLLECTION_SIZE` being a reasonably high number.

Even better, use a `List` instead of an array. That way you won't have to guess your library size beforehand:

```
List<Book> collection = new LinkedList<Book>();
```

Then `addBook` can look like this:

```
public void addBook(Book newBook)
{
    this.collection.add(newBook);
}
```

and you can get rid of `collectionCounter`. If you ever really need the number of books, you can get it using `this.collection.size()`.

Comment: When people post an answer one second before you can... exactly what I was going to say xD (apart from that I don't see why you would use `LinkedList` here instead of `ArrayList`).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, when you say that `addBook` can look like those four lines of code, do you mean in the case that I opt for the linked list approach or does it work with the array approach too?

Comment: @Frank Using `add` only works, if you choose to go for the `List` approach.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will accept answer as soon as I can, site says it will be in 2 minutes. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in your `Library` class.
It's `addBook` method uses `this.collection`, however this was only declared, hence still being `null`.

```
public void addBook(Book newBook)
{
    System.out.println(this.collectionCounter);
    this.collection[this.collectionCounter] = newBook;
    this.collectionCounter += 1;
}
```